# Javascript-Flask: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: javascript, python, flask, request

I want to send data from JS to Python. For this job I use this script:

```
function get_data(table, values,  name, keyword_column) {
            alert(table)
            alert("sending data")
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/data",
                    data: {
                        keyword: name,
                        table: table,
                        columns: JSON.stringify(values),
                        keyword_column: keyword_column
                    },
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                       return data;
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                 });
            //return false; // avoid actual submit
        }
```

Example input for the function above:

```
get_data('string',['item1','item2','item3'], 'string', 'string');
```

And Python:

```
@app.route("/data", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get_data():
    print('im here')
    print(str(request.form))
    table = request.form['table']
    keyword = request.form['keyword']
    columns = request.form['columns']
    keyword_column = request.form['keyword_column']
    print(table)
```

However when doing this I get the following error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\""\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\""\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "C:\Users\""\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "C:\Users\""\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1740, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "C:\Users\""\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers.py", line 885, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "C:\Users\""\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\test.py", line 884, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

As you can see I printed the request object, this seemed to be oke:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('keyword', 'S-t'), ('table', 'gene'), ('columns', '["gene_id","name","aliases","location","description"]'), ('keyword_column', 'name')])
```

It seems that `JSON.stringify` did it's job, however Flask still gives an error.

Comment: can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: What shows up in the Python process logs? There should be an exception there.

Comment: I added the full traceback @DSLima90

Comment: see edit @DanielPryden

Comment: I think your problem is related to the fact that you're not actually returning a Werkzeug response object (or other WSGI application object) from your `get_data` function. But I'm not quite sure how that becomes a `list` object (possibly something is rewriting `None` to `[]`)?

Comment: Oow thankyou! @DanielPryden I called some other function which eventually return ['item1','item2'] to the webpage via Flask but this list had to be converted to JSON as wel... so stupid. (I didn't include this in the code above because thought the error was caused by the above code)